Python WFDB library has no attribute ann2rr
I am trying to extract RR interval data from ecg annotation files from physionet by using the ann2rr function according to documentation:
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import posixpath

import wfdb

# Demo 1 - Read a WFDB record using the 'rdrecord' function into a wfdb.Record object.
# Plot the signals, and show the data.

# This works:
path = 'C:/Users/user/Downloads/bidmc-congestive-heart-failure-database-1.0.0/files/chf09'
ext ='ecg'
record = wfdb.rdrecord(path) 
wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=record, title='Record chf09 from BIDMC heart failure database') 
display(record.__dict__)
# but that generates the error:
res = wfdb.ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 10
      8 display(record.__dict__)
      9 sig=np.array(record.p_signal).T
---> 10 res = wfdb.processing.ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True)

AttributeError: module 'wfdb.processing' has no attribute 'ann2rr'


I have also tried the variant without processing, i.e. wfdb.ann2rr(...) also without success.
I also have reinstalled the wfdb and pyECG libraries, also without effect.
I'm working with Jupyter Notebook and python version
3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
Maybe I'm just missing something simple so I put my hopes on helpful replies

We need the full traceback, not just a snippet. Help others trying to help you by including links to the documentation you reference. For example, these links probably should be in your post: https://wfdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/blob/main/demo.ipynb

Can we rule out your your code vs. data vs. environment? Most of your provided code looks reminiscent of the first two code cells in the demo notebook.  Turns out that can asily be run in a new, clean environment for comparison without touching anyone's system. This is what I did to investigate more and try some things. Here is how you could if you are curious: Go to here and press the 'launch binder' badge. When the temporary ...

 remote Jupyter session spins up in your browser, open a terminal a run the following two commands. First run pip install wfdb and then git clone https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python.git . That will install the wfdb library and clone the resources associated with the demo. In the file navigator pane on the left side, you'll see a folder wfdb-python after the git clone step. Double click on the wfdb-python directory to go into it and then double click on the demo.ipynb notebook listed there and run the first two code cells. Those work as you a, bit confusingly, ...

 point out. ('That' would normally refer to what has already come before. Using # but THIS LINE BELOW generates the error would have been much clearer. Or better yet, a whole new paragraph covering the problem code.) But if I then try to run the line res = wfdb.ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True), I see the error you report. So it isn't your environment not matching. And it isn't the data because I downloaded that bidmc-congestive-heart-failure-database-1.0.0 and used that in the same session to rule that out as contributing. So definitely not data either. Plus a lot of other...

 things were demonstrated to work since that whole notebook worked and so it seems more particular...

Here buried in the code makes it clear you need to import processing separately:
    Examples
    --------
    >>> import wfdb
    >>> from wfdb import processing

Then you can use the annrr() function like the following:
processing.ann2rr()

And so for your example it would be changing res = wfdb.processing.ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True), or res = wfdb.ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True), to these two lines below:
from wfdb import processing
res = processing.ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True)

(By they way, please make the provided code and errors match in the future. This post is unnecessarily confusing with the problematic code appearing in two different forms, one of them buried in a code block introduced in a comment grammatically incorrectly.)
That new line will run without the error now.
I am not familiar with their documentation fully, but it does appear the exact syntax necessary doesn't match well the limited example here that reads below 'Examples' under wfdb.processing.ann2rr() in the processing subpackage documentation:
wfdb.ann2rr('sample-data/100', 'atr', as_array=False)

Plus, this SO post makes it clear one of the approaches you tried worked in the past.
The processing documentation page does at least say 'subpackage'. (This issue title 'error when running processing.ann2rr' also touched on the correct syntax.)
It is not unusual to need to hack around a bit for the exact syntax when using a large package in active development. Querying with dir() and searching around the codebase , example helpful search in codebase for this case. Or if you ran from wfdb import processing, you can then run dir(processing) to see ann2rr listed as the functions and methods under that.
If you look in the codebase, you'll see there's some other ways to import this that would work. For example, from here:
from wfdb.processing.hr import compute_hr, calc_rr, calc_mean_hr, ann2rr, rr2ann

And then you'd use the function like below since you have imported it directly into the current namespace:
res = ann2rr(path, ext, as_array=True)

